# What does three assignment operators in one line do?

Tags: c#, variable-assignment, equals

what does this line of code do?

```
boolean1 = boolean2 = boolean3;
```

what are the outputs, given lets say original values of boolean1 = true, boolean2 = false, boolean3 = true?

thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to open up a project, set a breakpoint and check yourself?

Comment: Or you could use LinqPad https://www.linqpad.net/CodeSnippetIDE.aspx

Answer (score 7):

It has the same effect as:

```
boolean2 = boolean3;
boolean1 = boolean2;
```

Given your scenario:

```
bool boolean1 = true;
bool boolean2 = false;
bool boolean3 = true;

boolean1 = boolean2 = boolean3;

// Final result:
//
// boolean1 = true
// boolean2 = true
// boolean3 = true
//
```

Answer (score 2):

This is doing multiple assignments on the one line. The assignments get resolved from right to left.
So, the value of boolean3 is assigned to boolean2, which is then assigned to boolean1.

The final value will be true for each of the variables

Answer (score 1):

They will all equal true.

1 is equal to 2. 2 is equal to 3. Since 3 is true, 2 is true, since 2 is true, 1 is true.

Answer (score 1):

Your values are assigned from the right to the left. So end of your statement `boolean1` and `boolean2` values will be equal to `boolean3`. If you add extra variable in the end of the chain, let's say `boolean4` all values will be equal to `boolean4's` value and so on...